# what is the 'availability_zone' argument in terraform for azure?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create a Virtual network in Azure with a NAT gateway, using terraform.

I'm getting the following warning when I run `terraform plan` :

```
Warning: Argument is deprecated
│ 
│   with azurerm_public_ip.example2,
│   on PublicIPandNAT.tf line 16, in resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example2":
│   16:   zones               = ["1"]
│ 
│ This property has been deprecated in favour of `availability_zone` due to a breaking behavioural change in Azure:
│ https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/zone-behavior-change/
│ 
│ (and one more similar warning elsewhere)
╵

Do you want to perform these actions?
```

But in the azurerm provider documentation on registry.terraform.io, there is no reference to a `availability_zone` argument in the `azurerm_public_ip` resource.

Is the terraform documentation out of date? what is the syntax of the `availability_zone` argument? and what is the risk of using the `zones` argument?

Comment: Could you please share full code ..?

Comment: Hello @Eliot Hersh , did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score -1):

> Trying to create a Virtual network in Azure with a NAT gateway, using
> terraform.

***To create Virtual network with NAT Gateway using terraform, we have tried at our end with following code and it works fine without any error***.

*You can use the below code to do the same by adding your required name :-*

`main.tf`:-

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "nat-gateway-example-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "nat-gateway-publicIP"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  zones               = ["1"]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  dns_servers         = ["10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip_prefix" "example" {
  name                = "nat-gateway-publicIPPrefix"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  prefix_length       = 30
  zones               = ["1"]
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway" "example" {
  name                    = "nat-Gateway"
  location                = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku_name                = "Standard"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 10
  zones                   = ["1"]
}
```

***OUTPUT DETAILS:-***
[image]
[image]

[image]

***My terraform version :-***
[image]

> what is the syntax of the availability_zone argument? and what is the
> risk of using the zones argument?

***AFAIK, there is no risk of use availability zone and you can find the reference in aforementioned code*** .

*For more information please refer this* HashiCorp| [***azurerm_nat_gateway***](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/nat_gateway)